# Insert custom html / css background to Wordpress

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I have the following problem:

- I want to add an custom (animated stars) background with html / css to wordpress
- To fill the whole height of an page I have to break the html-code (see img - I deleted the last closing div and put it on the end of the page to wrap the whole content inside the background)

**Question:**

 - How am I able to add the code without using a invalid code

**Ressources:**

 - https://codepen.io/saransh/pen/BKJun (the background)

**Images:**
 
 - open div [open the html code and break it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vN7pg.png)

 - close div [close last div to wrap whole website content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/921UZ.png)

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at bottom, #1b2735 0%, #090a0f 100%);
  overflow: hidden;
}

#stars {
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  background: transparent;
  box-shadow: 393px 383px #FFF , 1385px 882px #FFF , 1681px 1674px #FFF , 1677px 237px #FFF , 1659px 1990px #FFF , 1224px 1872px #FFF , 1955px 1284px #FFF , 39px 612px #FFF , 201px 856px #FFF , 1488px 1440px #FFF , 1102px 404px #FFF , 842px 769px #FFF , 697px 557px #FFF , 214px 1485px #FFF , 566px 1767px #FFF , 354px 148px #FFF , 952px 1429px #FFF , 1268px 1522px #FFF , 1105px 1876px #FFF , 1473px 3px #FFF , 1876px 777px #FFF , 196px 1971px #FFF , 1205px 1651px #FFF , 78px 780px #FFF , 436px 1250px #FFF , 127px 1625px #FFF , 762px 324px #FFF , 1505px 623px #FFF , 1518px 1618px #FFF , 589px 447px #FFF , 1913px 1060px #FFF , 176px 1307px #FFF , 445px 757px #FFF , 1547px 1231px #FFF , 605px 1215px #FFF , 1264px 216px #FFF , 1466px 777px #FFF , 511px 1356px #FFF , 1342px 1169px #FFF , 1305px 589px #FFF , 1496px 1391px #FFF , 483px 65px #FFF , 330px 1270px #FFF , 907px 606px #FFF , 256px 649px #FFF , 695px 701px #FFF , 1156px 974px #FFF , 1095px 927px #FFF , 1638px 1967px #FFF , 570px 495px #FFF , 783px 427px #FFF , 364px 1234px #FFF , 388px 1072px #FFF , 475px 233px #FFF , 1631px 1777px #FFF , 1651px 952px #FFF , 805px 1974px #FFF , 1144px 1949px #FFF , 1265px 991px #FFF , 1923px 955px #FFF , 1083px 226px #FFF , 468px 1818px #FFF , 1951px 1212px #FFF , 778px 1050px #FFF , 368px 207px #FFF , 1404px 654px #FFF , 251px 49px #FFF , 677px 1062px #FFF , 533px 1262px #FFF , 366px 1631px #FFF , 605px 496px #FFF , 1976px 1637px #FFF , 935px 1076px #FFF , 847px 241px #FFF , 1180px 648px #FFF , 937px 583px #FFF , 540px 1994px #FFF , 411px 1203px #FFF , 1046px 1790px #FFF , 1176px 930px #FFF , 829px 1623px #FFF , 391px 780px #FFF , 233px 411px #FFF , 484px 1131px #FFF , 576px 568px #FFF , 1833px 1653px #FFF , 1978px 942px #FFF , 1632px 754px #FFF , 1007px 1318px #FFF , 1028px 1883px #FFF , 1923px 1940px #FFF , 186px 750px #FFF , 1977px 364px #FFF , 1010px 148px #FFF , 180px 1005px #FFF , 586px 855px #FFF , 521px 699px #FFF , 1114px 659px #FFF , 231px 1550px #FFF , 703px 744px #FFF , 1366px 1172px #FFF , 1458px 1287px #FFF , 1254px 68px #FFF , 339px 1480px #FFF , 523px 921px #FFF , 352px 1678px #FFF , 1339px 1221px #FFF , 457px 1582px #FFF , 1146px 140px #FFF , 1621px 1304px #FFF , 710px 81px #FFF , 565px 751px #FFF , 314px 1641px #FFF , 41px 1052px #FFF , 578px 1202px #FFF , 1797px 810px #FFF , 2px 927px #FFF , 833px 785px #FFF , 1529px 471px #FFF , 279px 500px #FFF , 428px 31px #FFF , 37px 351px #FFF , 1003px 126px #FFF , 473px 405px #FFF , 1968px 1744px #FFF , 297px 328px #FFF , 1409px 1237px #FFF , 982px 1703px #FFF , 24px 1730px #FFF , 1450px 690px #FFF , 2000px 395px #FFF , 1313px 1641px #FFF , 625px 1474px #FFF , 1942px 1333px #FFF , 674px 1729px #FFF , 417px 1684px #FFF , 1499px 1405px #FFF , 296px 167px #FFF , 1276px 195px #FFF , 939px 180px #FFF , 1345px 1453px #FFF , 1613px 812px #FFF , 133px 321px #FFF , 465px 1104px #FFF , 1129px 1237px #FFF , 1104px 596px #FFF , 616px 1856px #FFF , 932px 188px #FFF , 1032px 931px #FFF , 1824px 92px #FFF , 1762px 94px #FFF , 908px 1424px #FFF , 1357px 452px #FFF , 963px 791px #FFF , 203px 67px #FFF , 801px 310px #FFF , 1414px 177px #FFF , 1789px 979px #FFF , 519px 1702px #FFF , 1767px 831px #FFF , 1780px 509px #FFF , 1133px 873px #FFF , 1831px 856px #FFF , 376px 1594px #FFF , 651px 23px #FFF , 1545px 788px #FFF , 942px 807px #FFF , 635px 1240px #FFF , 1822px 1995px #FFF , 1065px 1730px #FFF , 1746px 712px #FFF , 1591px 1477px #FFF , 1631px 959px #FFF , 1647px 1844px #FFF , 464px 228px #FFF , 492px 483px #FFF , 622px 348px #FFF , 1813px 1709px #FFF , 637px 849px #FFF , 1831px 260px #FFF , 753px 1970px #FFF , 1659px 1605px #FFF , 496px 1053px #FFF , 358px 1299px #FFF , 1549px 1406px #FFF , 1718px 1311px #FFF , 1435px 1873px #FFF , 129px 92px #FFF , 815px 1649px #FFF , 1153px 978px #FFF , 1496px 1371px #FFF , 1365px 1479px #FFF , 990px 836px #FFF , 78px 706px #FFF , 120px 1649px #FFF , 333px 1145px #FFF , 874px 1640px #FFF , 1295px 462px #FFF , 200px 1463px #FFF , 1990px 87px #FFF , 1407px 1113px #FFF , 494px 1238px #FFF , 1267px 904px #FFF , 1127px 1817px #FFF , 1389px 694px #FFF , 123px 1003px #FFF , 841px 1664px #FFF , 1053px 1361px #FFF , 1454px 1318px #FFF , 562px 246px #FFF , 1370px 1657px #FFF , 1698px 1853px #FFF , 1577px 1841px #FFF , 1732px 1889px #FFF , 224px 915px #FFF , 132px 187px #FFF , 306px 1592px #FFF , 1058px 520px #FFF , 1445px 1431px #FFF , 493px 1579px #FFF , 593px 1345px #FFF , 1350px 1599px #FFF , 1006px 1176px #FFF , 1146px 1467px #FFF , 1418px 1138px #FFF , 961px 1127px #FFF , 1810px 721px #FFF , 1200px 256px #FFF , 1985px 431px #FFF , 1875px 165px #FFF , 1901px 1961px #FFF , 342px 895px #FFF , 553px 1534px #FFF , 1488px 417px #FFF , 277px 1030px #FFF , 1615px 418px #FFF , 1043px 1733px #FFF , 1548px 635px #FFF , 573px 1543px #FFF , 303px 127px #FFF , 1271px 224px #FFF , 864px 299px #FFF , 44px 370px #FFF , 97px 1935px #FFF , 1851px 415px #FFF , 1926px 152px #FFF , 1173px 1070px #FFF , 1287px 1770px #FFF , 1966px 1730px #FFF , 1544px 1818px #FFF , 1307px 271px #FFF , 1933px 1131px #FFF , 1347px 390px #FFF , 874px 1071px #FFF , 1216px 115px #FFF , 1979px 1892px #FFF , 315px 958px #FFF , 614px 1785px #FFF , 1471px 29px #FFF , 1228px 575px #FFF , 185px 1335px #FFF , 765px 1090px #FFF , 1726px 488px #FFF , 474px 833px #FFF , 412px 420px #FFF , 1417px 120px #FFF , 1094px 1284px #FFF , 1862px 1070px #FFF , 1464px 1138px #FFF , 871px 1013px #FFF , 830px 1779px #FFF , 1476px 838px #FFF , 553px 1888px #FFF , 552px 940px #FFF , 255px 610px #FFF , 236px 1094px #FFF , 141px 565px #FFF , 1776px 303px #FFF , 1933px 438px #FFF , 195px 1019px #FFF , 120px 1968px #FFF , 277px 957px #FFF , 1381px 886px #FFF , 387px 1389px #FFF , 512px 118px #FFF , 232px 1814px #FFF , 647px 1058px #FFF , 240px 651px #FFF , 1462px 1247px #FFF , 1921px 1261px #FFF , 760px 752px #FFF , 1054px 729px #FFF , 208px 1753px #FFF , 1988px 1689px #FFF , 995px 283px #FFF , 1884px 732px #FFF , 204px 1730px #FFF , 1144px 120px #FFF , 940px 295px #FFF , 1577px 1163px #FFF , 147px 1864px #FFF , 1550px 176px #FFF , 721px 212px #FFF , 329px 577px #FFF , 233px 172px #FFF , 1350px 191px #FFF , 634px 1799px #FFF , 487px 1500px #FFF , 764px 1623px #FFF , 1044px 865px #FFF , 986px 1416px #FFF , 409px 406px #FFF , 273px 366px #FFF , 488px 1918px #FFF , 373px 900px #FFF , 330px 636px #FFF , 218px 809px #FFF , 569px 1019px #FFF , 292px 301px #FFF , 98px 1616px #FFF , 315px 907px #FFF , 1488px 1468px #FFF , 1206px 179px #FFF , 1691px 1401px #FFF , 100px 854px #FFF , 18px 1522px #FFF , 1711px 1455px #FFF , 1582px 1540px #FFF , 264px 867px #FFF , 2000px 1476px #FFF , 997px 1993px #FFF , 1310px 354px #FFF , 1100px 800px #FFF , 1391px 1647px #FFF , 494px 1879px #FFF , 644px 1787px #FFF , 1366px 1726px #FFF , 1397px 238px #FFF , 301px 1967px #FFF , 1222px 553px #FFF , 1625px 47px #FFF , 296px 697px #FFF , 1143px 130px #FFF , 1765px 564px #FFF , 1122px 873px #FFF , 194px 214px #FFF , 1143px 806px #FFF , 209px 517px #FFF , 867px 994px #FFF , 765px 636px #FFF , 1665px 954px #FFF , 1209px 418px #FFF , 778px 1825px #FFF , 1752px 1417px #FFF , 1931px 670px #FFF , 1836px 473px #FFF , 525px 77px #FFF , 286px 294px #FFF , 605px 459px #FFF , 728px 1166px #FFF , 1619px 1062px #FFF , 96px 1898px #FFF , 1486px 1748px #FFF , 1867px 43px #FFF , 545px 1111px #FFF , 190px 1874px #FFF , 1159px 881px #FFF , 907px 1722px #FFF , 547px 191px #FFF , 1519px 1519px #FFF , 105px 1608px #FFF , 225px 169px #FFF , 188px 1207px #FFF , 1050px 825px #FFF , 1460px 1553px #FFF , 1334px 172px #FFF , 615px 787px #FFF , 1244px 1200px #FFF , 1484px 1648px #FFF , 1531px 1029px #FFF , 954px 740px #FFF , 636px 1904px #FFF , 551px 857px #FFF , 854px 498px #FFF , 47px 1940px #FFF , 599px 1388px #FFF , 1938px 905px #FFF , 1083px 200px #FFF , 176px 1998px #FFF , 1667px 1133px #FFF , 321px 1728px #FFF , 1511px 272px #FFF , 1068px 1362px #FFF , 523px 260px #FFF , 1744px 1270px #FFF , 989px 1115px #FFF , 848px 1941px #FFF , 1942px 1170px #FFF , 1689px 220px #FFF , 374px 1009px #FFF , 731px 93px #FFF , 580px 214px #FFF , 1968px 1295px #FFF , 383px 1803px #FFF , 1574px 1548px #FFF , 1258px 45px #FFF , 177px 1828px #FFF , 1168px 254px #FFF , 967px 1672px #FFF , 89px 1382px #FFF , 920px 694px #FFF , 703px 813px #FFF , 370px 528px #FFF , 1080px 1259px #FFF , 1225px 1615px #FFF , 1808px 1202px #FFF , 951px 657px #FFF , 1102px 1439px #FFF , 1400px 1978px #FFF , 363px 809px #FFF , 902px 706px #FFF , 1631px 502px #FFF , 389px 999px #FFF , 1756px 804px #FFF , 1040px 1313px #FFF , 917px 1684px #FFF , 190px 1720px #FFF , 247px 33px #FFF , 770px 540px #FFF , 1834px 369px #FFF , 1339px 462px #FFF , 1725px 405px #FFF , 512px 568px #FFF , 1053px 1833px #FFF , 1888px 1480px #FFF , 611px 564px #FFF , 1610px 727px #FFF , 831px 1371px #FFF , 701px 1370px #FFF , 1054px 1105px #FFF , 437px 727px #FFF , 1661px 846px #FFF , 395px 161px #FFF , 1414px 1043px #FFF , 762px 424px #FFF , 798px 131px #FFF , 902px 44px #FFF , 848px 1596px #FFF , 1820px 571px #FFF , 47px 684px #FFF , 29px 1051px #FFF , 107px 1004px #FFF , 1544px 1302px #FFF , 121px 776px #FFF , 1274px 1854px #FFF , 1786px 340px #FFF , 1606px 144px #FFF , 507px 1864px #FFF , 257px 638px #FFF , 367px 1960px #FFF , 1121px 1467px #FFF , 1021px 1826px #FFF , 635px 1381px #FFF , 707px 850px #FFF , 627px 1660px #FFF , 70px 728px #FFF , 1812px 947px #FFF , 923px 878px #FFF , 129px 802px #FFF , 937px 1209px #FFF , 328px 770px #FFF , 1526px 507px #FFF , 1373px 1099px #FFF , 93px 1674px #FFF , 450px 607px #FFF , 324px 266px #FFF , 1725px 1715px #FFF , 828px 269px #FFF , 1183px 1384px #FFF , 650px 150px #FFF , 764px 1935px #FFF , 1535px 81px #FFF , 523px 1310px #FFF , 1749px 518px #FFF , 71px 591px #FFF , 14px 319px #FFF , 109px 1166px #FFF , 1592px 1076px #FFF , 540px 521px #FFF , 42px 754px #FFF , 1594px 1167px #FFF , 1577px 511px #FFF , 1120px 425px #FFF , 460px 1079px #FFF , 1106px 901px #FFF , 1744px 680px #FFF , 1329px 1879px #FFF , 1193px 208px #FFF , 999px 1356px #FFF , 599px 439px #FFF , 1220px 479px #FFF , 140px 763px #FFF , 1387px 1803px #FFF , 743px 1351px #FFF , 1444px 716px #FFF , 628px 597px #FFF , 123px 956px #FFF , 293px 997px #FFF , 1222px 1186px #FFF , 1075px 741px #FFF , 1462px 1853px #FFF , 1768px 1121px #FFF , 1054px 1134px #FFF , 1923px 343px #FFF , 1678px 544px #FFF , 1228px 339px #FFF , 1585px 368px #FFF , 446px 1111px #FFF , 1771px 640px #FFF , 647px 1095px #FFF , 826px 764px #FFF , 369px 1476px #FFF , 1364px 1085px #FFF , 1386px 1823px #FFF , 1776px 678px #FFF , 1474px 1510px #FFF , 953px 1003px #FFF , 1935px 1007px #FFF , 831px 1018px #FFF , 572px 1946px #FFF , 77px 521px #FFF , 1826px 466px #FFF , 754px 1462px #FFF , 825px 1158px #FFF , 1863px 1654px #FFF , 1487px 1343px #FFF , 1424px 657px #FFF , 798px 150px #FFF , 1102px 1753px #FFF , 809px 1695px #FFF , 1056px 1767px #FFF , 1386px 1654px #FFF , 1099px 912px #FFF , 406px 615px #FFF , 1196px 7px #FFF , 981px 333px #FFF , 179px 1885px #FFF , 785px 1676px #FFF , 1816px 949px #FFF , 1586px 1332px #FFF , 711px 1022px #FFF , 1108px 655px #FFF , 308px 1307px #FFF , 408px 1826px #FFF , 1142px 224px #FFF , 369px 50px #FFF , 263px 1515px #FFF , 1344px 137px #FFF , 469px 521px #FFF , 1968px 1636px #FFF , 874px 785px #FFF , 454px 1615px #FFF , 1272px 1502px #FFF , 977px 84px #FFF , 598px 1049px #FFF , 420px 1085px #FFF , 1389px 1609px #FFF , 1726px 851px #FFF , 284px 1487px #FFF , 1208px 726px #FFF , 168px 1489px #FFF , 1100px 528px #FFF , 1561px 1015px #FFF , 758px 1166px #FFF , 1682px 276px #FFF , 1231px 18px #FFF , 1668px 1916px #FFF , 1716px 278px #FFF , 851px 421px #FFF , 214px 512px #FFF , 1092px 883px #FFF , 1100px 313px #FFF , 1976px 1225px #FFF , 1722px 894px #FFF , 1167px 1577px #FFF , 516px 1873px #FFF , 1737px 1861px #FFF , 1249px 639px #FFF , 513px 1138px #FFF , 679px 1990px #FFF , 1422px 1900px #FFF , 1582px 486px #FFF , 823px 1963px #FFF , 741px 1176px #FFF , 982px 1622px #FFF , 894px 1243px #FFF , 392px 527px #FFF , 1718px 410px #FFF , 91px 186px #FFF , 1970px 1878px #FFF , 1540px 729px #FFF , 783px 1347px #FFF , 838px 1431px #FFF , 105px 1601px #FFF , 78px 1380px #FFF , 1997px 948px #FFF , 1255px 1745px #FFF , 810px 1862px #FFF , 1907px 535px #FFF , 1046px 1279px #FFF , 231px 847px #FFF , 93px 1619px #FFF , 1069px 614px #FFF , 1104px 801px #FFF , 1999px 667px #FFF , 38px 698px #FFF , 620px 61px #FFF , 1592px 1799px #FFF , 225px 1667px #FFF , 316px 1390px #FFF , 814px 1218px #FFF , 542px 1526px #FFF , 1198px 1558px #FFF , 1483px 1283px #FFF , 1746px 608px #FFF , 994px 1851px #FFF , 1671px 86px #FFF , 276px 768px #FFF , 897px 428px #FFF , 1087px 1161px #FFF , 1703px 1162px #FFF , 1543px 1795px #FFF , 1214px 1734px #FFF , 342px 766px #FFF , 990px 1208px #FFF , 1862px 266px #FFF , 260px 291px #FFF , 573px 737px #FFF , 727px 841px #FFF , 704px 1955px #FFF , 1339px 307px #FFF , 897px 1697px #FFF , 1037px 1196px #FFF , 427px 191px #FFF , 1648px 349px #FFF , 187px 412px #FFF , 317px 1442px #FFF , 1885px 1116px #FFF , 750px 1534px #FFF , 799px 31px #FFF , 1255px 1242px #FFF , 459px 1156px #FFF , 377px 780px #FFF , 119px 1181px #FFF , 834px 514px #FFF , 1606px 659px #FFF , 1391px 853px #FFF , 1933px 435px #FFF , 73px 68px #FFF , 113px 815px #FFF , 756px 1680px #FFF , 895px 1910px #FFF , 193px 1922px #FFF , 384px 1898px #FFF , 1249px 654px #FFF , 1512px 445px #FFF , 540px 631px #FFF , 660px 641px #FFF , 27px 429px #FFF , 31px 1984px #FFF , 1792px 723px #FFF , 1260px 503px #FFF , 1757px 807px #FFF , 1386px 542px #FFF , 1061px 1489px #FFF , 597px 130px #FFF , 781px 620px #FFF , 1513px 210px #FFF;
  animation: animStar 50s linear infinite;
}
#stars:after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  top: 2000px;
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  background: transparent;
  box-shadow: 393px 383px #FFF , 1385px 882px #FFF , 1681px 1674px #FFF , 1677px 237px #FFF , 1659px 1990px #FFF , 1224px 1872px #FFF , 1955px 1284px #FFF , 39px 612px #FFF , 201px 856px #FFF , 1488px 1440px #FFF , 1102px 404px #FFF , 842px 769px #FFF , 697px 557px #FFF , 214px 1485px #FFF , 566px 1767px #FFF , 354px 148px #FFF , 952px 1429px #FFF , 1268px 1522px #FFF , 1105px 1876px #FFF , 1473px 3px #FFF , 1876px 777px #FFF , 196px 1971px #FFF , 1205px 1651px #FFF , 78px 780px #FFF , 436px 1250px #FFF , 127px 1625px #FFF , 762px 324px #FFF , 1505px 623px #FFF , 1518px 1618px #FFF , 589px 447px #FFF , 1913px 1060px #FFF , 176px 1307px #FFF , 445px 757px #FFF , 1547px 1231px #FFF , 605px 1215px #FFF , 1264px 216px #FFF , 1466px 777px #FFF , 511px 1356px #FFF , 1342px 1169px #FFF , 1305px 589px #FFF , 1496px 1391px #FFF , 483px 65px #FFF , 330px 1270px #FFF , 907px 606px #FFF , 256px 649px #FFF , 695px 701px #FFF , 1156px 974px #FFF , 1095px 927px #FFF , 1638px 1967px #FFF , 570px 495px #FFF , 783px 427px #FFF , 364px 1234px #FFF , 1599px 2000px #FFF , 1854px 975px #FFF , 985px 1356px #FFF , 1615px 355px #FFF , 1161px 441px #FFF , 1911px 928px #FFF , 457px 77px #FFF , 1426px 1370px #FFF , 1903px 1193px #FFF , 168px 257px #FFF , 405px 98px #FFF , 982px 996px #FFF , 30px 1664px #FFF , 1554px 11px #FFF , 1367px 1155px #FFF , 1755px 1242px #FFF , 388px 1072px #FFF , 475px 233px #FFF , 1631px 1777px #FFF , 1651px 952px #FFF , 805px 1974px #FFF , 1144px 1949px #FFF , 1265px 991px #FFF , 1923px 955px #FFF , 1083px 226px #FFF , 468px 1818px #FFF , 1951px 1212px #FFF , 778px 1050px #FFF , 368px 207px #FFF , 1404px 654px #FFF , 251px 49px #FFF , 677px 1062px #FFF , 1721px 1096px #FFF , 706px 545px #FFF , 533px 1262px #FFF , 366px 1631px #FFF , 605px 496px #FFF , 1976px 1637px #FFF , 935px 1076px #FFF , 847px 241px #FFF , 1180px 648px #FFF , 937px 583px #FFF , 540px 1994px #FFF , 411px 1203px #FFF , 1046px 1790px #FFF , 1176px 930px #FFF , 829px 1623px #FFF , 391px 780px #FFF , 233px 411px #FFF , 484px 1131px #FFF , 576px 568px #FFF , 1833px 1653px #FFF , 1978px 942px #FFF , 1632px 754px #FFF , 1007px 1318px #FFF , 1028px 1883px #FFF , 1923px 1940px #FFF , 186px 750px #FFF , 1977px 364px #FFF , 1010px 148px #FFF , 180px 1005px #FFF , 586px 855px #FFF , 521px 699px #FFF , 1114px 659px #FFF , 231px 1550px #FFF , 703px 744px #FFF , 1366px 1172px #FFF , 1458px 1287px #FFF , 1254px 68px #FFF , 339px 1480px #FFF , 523px 921px #FFF , 352px 1678px #FFF , 1339px 1221px #FFF , 457px 1582px #FFF , 1146px 140px #FFF , 1621px 1304px #FFF , 710px 81px #FFF , 565px 751px #FFF , 314px 1641px #FFF , 41px 1052px #FFF , 578px 1202px #FFF , 1797px 810px #FFF , 2px 927px #FFF , 833px 785px #FFF , 1529px 471px #FFF , 279px 500px #FFF , 428px 31px #FFF , 37px 351px #FFF , 1003px 126px #FFF , 473px 405px #FFF , 1968px 1744px #FFF , 297px 328px #FFF , 1409px 1237px #FFF , 982px 1703px #FFF , 24px 1730px #FFF , 1450px 690px #FFF , 2000px 395px #FFF , 1313px 1641px #FFF , 625px 1474px #FFF , 1942px 1333px #FFF , 674px 1729px #FFF , 417px 1684px #FFF , 1499px 1405px #FFF , 296px 167px #FFF , 1276px 195px #FFF , 939px 180px #FFF , 1345px 1453px #FFF , 1613px 812px #FFF , 133px 321px #FFF , 465px 1104px #FFF , 1129px 1237px #FFF , 1104px 596px #FFF , 616px 1856px #FFF , 932px 188px #FFF , 1032px 931px #FFF , 1824px 92px #FFF , 1762px 94px #FFF , 908px 1424px #FFF , 1357px 452px #FFF , 963px 791px #FFF , 203px 67px #FFF , 801px 310px #FFF , 1414px 177px #FFF , 1789px 979px #FFF , 519px 1702px #FFF , 1767px 831px #FFF , 1780px 509px #FFF , 1133px 873px #FFF , 1831px 856px #FFF , 376px 1594px #FFF , 651px 23px #FFF , 1545px 788px #FFF , 942px 807px #FFF , 635px 1240px #FFF , 1822px 1995px #FFF , 1065px 1730px #FFF , 1746px 712px #FFF , 1591px 1477px #FFF , 1631px 959px #FFF , 1647px 1844px #FFF , 464px 228px #FFF , 492px 483px #FFF , 622px 348px #FFF , 1813px 1709px #FFF , 637px 849px #FFF , 1831px 260px #FFF , 753px 1970px #FFF , 1659px 1605px #FFF , 496px 1053px #FFF , 358px 1299px #FFF , 1549px 1406px #FFF , 1718px 1311px #FFF , 1435px 1873px #FFF , 129px 92px #FFF , 815px 1649px #FFF , 1153px 978px #FFF , 1496px 1371px #FFF , 1365px 1479px #FFF , 990px 836px #FFF , 78px 706px #FFF , 120px 1649px #FFF , 333px 1145px #FFF , 874px 1640px #FFF , 1295px 462px #FFF , 200px 1463px #FFF , 1990px 87px #FFF , 1407px 1113px #FFF , 494px 1238px #FFF , 1267px 904px #FFF , 1127px 1817px #FFF , 1389px 694px #FFF , 123px 1003px #FFF , 841px 1664px #FFF , 1053px 1361px #FFF , 1454px 1318px #FFF , 562px 246px #FFF , 1370px 1657px #FFF , 1698px 1853px #FFF , 1577px 1841px #FFF , 1732px 1889px #FFF , 224px 915px #FFF , 132px 187px #FFF , 306px 1592px #FFF , 1058px 520px #FFF , 1445px 1431px #FFF , 493px 1579px #FFF , 593px 1345px #FFF , 1350px 1599px #FFF , 1006px 1176px #FFF , 1146px 1467px #FFF , 1418px 1138px #FFF , 961px 1127px #FFF , 1810px 721px #FFF , 1200px 256px #FFF , 1985px 431px #FFF , 1875px 165px #FFF , 1901px 1961px #FFF , 342px 895px #FFF , 553px 1534px #FFF , 1488px 417px #FFF , 277px 1030px #FFF , 1615px 418px #FFF , 1043px 1733px #FFF , 1548px 635px #FFF , 573px 1543px #FFF , 303px 127px #FFF , 1271px 224px #FFF , 864px 299px #FFF , 44px 370px #FFF , 97px 1935px #FFF , 1851px 415px #FFF , 1926px 152px #FFF , 1173px 1070px #FFF , 1287px 1770px #FFF , 1966px 1730px #FFF , 1544px 1818px #FFF , 1307px 271px #FFF , 1933px 1131px #FFF , 1347px 390px #FFF , 874px 1071px #FFF , 1216px 115px #FFF , 1979px 1892px #FFF , 315px 958px #FFF , 614px 1785px #FFF , 1471px 29px #FFF , 1228px 575px #FFF , 185px 1335px #FFF , 765px 1090px #FFF , 1726px 488px #FFF , 474px 833px #FFF , 412px 420px #FFF , 1417px 120px #FFF , 1094px 1284px #FFF , 1862px 1070px #FFF , 1464px 1138px #FFF , 871px 1013px #FFF , 830px 1779px #FFF , 1476px 838px #FFF , 553px 1888px #FFF , 552px 940px #FFF , 255px 610px #FFF , 236px 1094px #FFF , 141px 565px #FFF , 1776px 303px #FFF , 1933px 438px #FFF , 195px 1019px #FFF , 120px 1968px #FFF , 277px 957px #FFF , 1381px 886px #FFF , 387px 1389px #FFF , 512px 118px #FFF , 232px 1814px #FFF , 647px 1058px #FFF , 240px 651px #FFF , 1462px 1247px #FFF , 1921px 1261px #FFF , 760px 752px #FFF , 1054px 729px #FFF , 208px 1753px #FFF , 1988px 1689px #FFF , 995px 283px #FFF , 1884px 732px #FFF , 204px 1730px #FFF , 1144px 120px #FFF , 940px 295px #FFF , 1577px 1163px #FFF , 147px 1864px #FFF , 1550px 176px #FFF , 721px 212px #FFF , 329px 577px #FFF , 233px 172px #FFF , 1350px 191px #FFF , 634px 1799px #FFF , 487px 1500px #FFF , 764px 1623px #FFF , 1044px 865px #FFF , 986px 1416px #FFF , 409px 406px #FFF , 273px 366px #FFF , 488px 1918px #FFF , 373px 900px #FFF , 330px 636px #FFF , 218px 809px #FFF , 569px 1019px #FFF , 292px 301px #FFF , 98px 1616px #FFF , 315px 907px #FFF , 1488px 1468px #FFF , 1206px 179px #FFF , 1691px 1401px #FFF , 100px 854px #FFF , 18px 1522px #FFF , 1711px 1455px #FFF , 1582px 1540px #FFF , 264px 867px #FFF , 2000px 1476px #FFF , 997px 1993px #FFF , 1310px 354px #FFF , 1100px 800px #FFF , 1391px 1647px #FFF , 494px 1879px #FFF , 644px 1787px #FFF , 1366px 1726px #FFF , 1397px 238px #FFF , 301px 1967px #FFF , 1222px 553px #FFF , 1625px 47px #FFF , 296px 697px #FFF , 1143px 130px #FFF , 1765px 564px #FFF , 1122px 873px #FFF , 194px 214px #FFF , 1143px 806px #FFF , 209px 517px #FFF , 867px 994px #FFF , 765px 636px #FFF , 1665px 954px #FFF , 1209px 418px #FFF , 778px 1825px #FFF , 1752px 1417px #FFF , 1931px 670px #FFF , 1836px 473px #FFF , 525px 77px #FFF , 286px 294px #FFF , 605px 459px #FFF , 728px 1166px #FFF , 1619px 1062px #FFF , 96px 1898px #FFF , 1486px 1748px #FFF , 1867px 43px #FFF , 545px 1111px #FFF , 190px 1874px #FFF , 1159px 881px #FFF , 907px 1722px #FFF , 547px 191px #FFF , 1519px 1519px #FFF , 105px 1608px #FFF , 225px 169px #FFF , 188px 1207px #FFF , 1050px 825px #FFF , 1460px 1553px #FFF , 1334px 172px #FFF , 615px 787px #FFF , 1244px 1200px #FFF , 1484px 1648px #FFF , 1531px 1029px #FFF , 954px 740px #FFF , 636px 1904px #FFF , 551px 857px #FFF , 854px 498px #FFF , 47px 1940px #FFF , 599px 1388px #FFF , 1938px 905px #FFF , 1083px 200px #FFF , 176px 1998px #FFF , 1667px 1133px #FFF , 321px 1728px #FFF , 1511px 272px #FFF , 1068px 1362px #FFF , 523px 260px #FFF , 1744px 1270px #FFF , 989px 1115px #FFF , 848px 1941px #FFF , 1942px 1170px #FFF , 1689px 220px #FFF , 374px 1009px #FFF , 731px 93px #FFF , 580px 214px #FFF , 1968px 1295px #FFF , 383px 1803px #FFF , 1574px 1548px #FFF , 1258px 45px #FFF , 177px 1828px #FFF , 1168px 254px #FFF , 967px 1672px #FFF , 89px 1382px #FFF , 920px 694px #FFF , 703px 813px #FFF , 370px 528px #FFF , 1080px 1259px #FFF , 1225px 1615px #FFF , 1808px 1202px #FFF , 951px 657px #FFF , 1102px 1439px #FFF , 1400px 1978px #FFF , 363px 809px #FFF , 902px 706px #FFF , 1631px 502px #FFF , 389px 999px #FFF , 1756px 804px #FFF , 1040px 1313px #FFF , 917px 1684px #FFF , 190px 1720px #FFF , 247px 33px #FFF , 770px 540px #FFF , 1834px 369px #FFF , 1339px 462px #FFF , 1725px 405px #FFF , 512px 568px #FFF , 1053px 1833px #FFF , 1888px 1480px #FFF , 611px 564px #FFF , 1610px 727px #FFF , 831px 1371px #FFF , 701px 1370px #FFF , 1054px 1105px #FFF , 437px 727px #FFF , 1661px 846px #FFF , 395px 161px #FFF , 1414px 1043px #FFF , 762px 424px #FFF , 798px 131px #FFF , 902px 44px #FFF , 848px 1596px #FFF , 1820px 571px #FFF , 47px 684px #FFF , 29px 1051px #FFF , 107px 1004px #FFF , 1544px 1302px #FFF , 121px 776px #FFF , 1274px 1854px #FFF , 1786px 340px #FFF , 1606px 144px #FFF , 507px 1864px #FFF , 257px 638px #FFF , 367px 1960px #FFF , 1121px 1467px #FFF , 1021px 1826px #FFF , 635px 1381px #FFF , 707px 850px #FFF , 627px 1660px #FFF , 70px 728px #FFF , 1812px 947px #FFF , 923px 878px #FFF , 129px 802px #FFF , 937px 1209px #FFF , 328px 770px #FFF , 1526px 507px #FFF , 1373px 1099px #FFF , 93px 1674px #FFF , 450px 607px #FFF , 1599px 1763px #FFF , 324px 266px #FFF , 1725px 1715px #FFF , 828px 269px #FFF , 1183px 1384px #FFF , 650px 150px #FFF , 764px 1935px #FFF , 1782px 1940px #FFF , 60px 1605px #FFF , 1544px 630px #FFF , 1535px 81px #FFF , 523px 1310px #FFF , 1749px 518px #FFF , 71px 591px #FFF , 14px 319px #FFF , 109px 1166px #FFF , 1592px 1076px #FFF , 540px 521px #FFF , 42px 754px #FFF , 1594px 1167px #FFF , 1577px 511px #FFF , 1120px 425px #FFF , 460px 1079px #FFF , 1106px 901px #FFF , 1744px 680px #FFF , 1329px 1879px #FFF , 1193px 208px #FFF , 999px 1356px #FFF , 599px 439px #FFF , 1220px 479px #FFF , 140px 763px #FFF , 1387px 1803px #FFF , 743px 1351px #FFF , 1444px 716px #FFF , 628px 597px #FFF , 123px 956px #FFF , 293px 997px #FFF , 1222px 1186px #FFF , 1075px 741px #FFF , 1462px 1853px #FFF , 1768px 1121px #FFF , 1054px 1134px #FFF , 1923px 343px #FFF , 1678px 544px #FFF , 1228px 339px #FFF , 1585px 368px #FFF , 446px 1111px #FFF , 1771px 640px #FFF , 647px 1095px #FFF , 826px 764px #FFF , 369px 1476px #FFF , 1364px 1085px #FFF , 1386px 1823px #FFF , 1776px 678px #FFF , 1474px 1510px #FFF , 953px 1003px #FFF , 1935px 1007px #FFF , 831px 1018px #FFF , 572px 1946px #FFF , 77px 521px #FFF , 1826px 466px #FFF , 754px 1462px #FFF , 825px 1158px #FFF , 1863px 1654px #FFF , 1487px 1343px #FFF , 1424px 657px #FFF , 798px 150px #FFF , 1102px 1753px #FFF , 809px 1695px #FFF , 1056px 1767px #FFF , 1386px 1654px #FFF , 1099px 912px #FFF , 406px 615px #FFF , 1196px 7px #FFF , 981px 333px #FFF , 179px 1885px #FFF , 785px 1676px #FFF , 1816px 949px #FFF , 1586px 1332px #FFF , 711px 1022px #FFF , 1108px 655px #FFF , 308px 1307px #FFF , 408px 1826px #FFF , 1142px 224px #FFF , 369px 50px #FFF , 263px 1515px #FFF , 1344px 137px #FFF , 469px 521px #FFF , 1968px 1636px #FFF , 874px 785px #FFF , 454px 1615px #FFF , 1272px 1502px #FFF , 977px 84px #FFF , 598px 1049px #FFF , 420px 1085px #FFF , 1389px 1609px #FFF , 1726px 851px #FFF , 284px 1487px #FFF , 1208px 726px #FFF , 168px 1489px #FFF , 1100px 528px #FFF , 1561px 1015px #FFF , 758px 1166px #FFF , 1682px 276px #FFF , 1231px 18px #FFF , 1668px 1916px #FFF , 1716px 278px #FFF , 851px 421px #FFF , 214px 512px #FFF , 1092px 883px #FFF , 1100px 313px #FFF , 1976px 1225px #FFF , 1722px 894px #FFF , 1167px 1577px #FFF , 516px 1873px #FFF , 1737px 1861px #FFF , 1249px 639px #FFF , 513px 1138px #FFF , 679px 1990px #FFF , 1422px 1900px #FFF , 1582px 486px #FFF , 823px 1963px #FFF , 741px 1176px #FFF , 982px 1622px #FFF , 894px 1243px #FFF , 392px 527px #FFF , 1718px 410px #FFF , 91px 186px #FFF , 1970px 1878px #FFF , 1540px 729px #FFF , 783px 1347px #FFF , 838px 1431px #FFF , 105px 1601px #FFF , 78px 1380px #FFF , 1997px 948px #FFF , 1255px 1745px #FFF , 810px 1862px #FFF , 1907px 535px #FFF , 1046px 1279px #FFF , 231px 847px #FFF , 93px 1619px #FFF , 1069px 614px #FFF , 1104px 801px #FFF , 1999px 667px #FFF , 38px 698px #FFF , 620px 61px #FFF , 1592px 1799px #FFF , 225px 1667px #FFF , 316px 1390px #FFF , 814px 1218px #FFF , 542px 1526px #FFF , 1198px 1558px #FFF , 1483px 1283px #FFF , 1746px 608px #FFF , 994px 1851px #FFF , 1671px 86px #FFF , 276px 768px #FFF , 897px 428px #FFF , 1087px 1161px #FFF , 1703px 1162px #FFF , 1543px 1795px #FFF , 1214px 1734px #FFF , 342px 766px #FFF , 990px 1208px #FFF , 1862px 266px #FFF , 260px 291px #FFF , 573px 737px #FFF , 727px 841px #FFF , 704px 1955px #FFF , 1339px 307px #FFF , 897px 1697px #FFF , 1037px 1196px #FFF , 427px 191px #FFF , 1648px 349px #FFF , 187px 412px #FFF , 317px 1442px #FFF , 1885px 1116px #FFF , 750px 1534px #FFF , 799px 31px #FFF , 1255px 1242px #FFF , 459px 1156px #FFF , 377px 780px #FFF , 119px 1181px #FFF , 834px 514px #FFF , 1606px 659px #FFF , 1391px 853px #FFF , 1933px 435px #FFF , 73px 68px #FFF , 113px 815px #FFF , 756px 1680px #FFF , 895px 1910px #FFF , 193px 1922px #FFF , 384px 1898px #FFF , 1249px 654px #FFF , 1512px 445px #FFF , 540px 631px #FFF , 660px 641px #FFF , 27px 429px #FFF , 31px 1984px #FFF , 1792px 723px #FFF , 1260px 503px #FFF , 1757px 807px #FFF , 1386px 542px #FFF , 1061px 1489px #FFF , 597px 130px #FFF , 781px 620px #FFF , 1513px 210px #FFF;
}

#title {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "lato", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 50px;
  letter-spacing: 10px;
  margin-top: -60px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
#title span {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(white, #38495a);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

@keyframes animStar {
  from {
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateY(-2000px);
  }
}
```

```html
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<div id='stars'></div>
<div id='stars2'></div>
<div id='stars3'></div>
<div id='title'>
  <span>
    PURE CSS
  </span>
  <br>
  <span>
    PARALLAX PIXEL STARS
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe here the issue is that you are trying to use the example code not 100% correctly in order to integrate it into your WordPress site. In the example, as shown above, it shows that the star divs themselves are not actually being wrapped around the content, yet they are elements that are being opened and closed at the top of the page.

Assuming you have a dark body background like in the example (#2b2b2b), all that you would need to do is have the same star divs at the top most part of your body.

Here's an example of the markup:

```
<body>
    <!-- these are the elements  -->
    <div id="stars"></div>
    <div id="stars2"></div>
    <div id="stars3"></div>
</body>
```

If the CSS and the JavaScript from the example is used and referenced accordingly within your WordPress theme, the stars should be animated the same way they are in your example. The important thing here to remember is that you don't actually need to wrap your content around these divs, they simply need to sit above everything you want them to animate over.